# Xcode Crash each as soon as I open my project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

Everything worked fine yesterday but this morning XCode crash as soon as I open my project.

Any suggestions??

---

The crash dialog says

> Internal error
>
> Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to
>   continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.  Choose "Crash" to
>   halt Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will
>   result in the loss of all unsaved data.

and if I click on  "show details" the following info is shown

> ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-287/Framework/Classes/Model/SourceControl/IDESourceControlTree.m:2548
>   Details:  (addedItem) should not be nil. Object:
>    Method:
>   -mergeStatusOperationResults:forLocalStatusOnly: Thread:   {name = (null), num = 11} Hints:   None Backtrace:   0 
>   0x0000000100949773 -[IDEAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in IDEKit)   1  0x000000010006d394 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in
>   DVTFoundation)   2  0x000000010055e1c1
>   __78-[IDESourceControlWorkingTree
>   mergeStatusOperationResults:forLocalStatusOnly:]_block_invoke_0 (in
>   IDEFoundation)   3  0x0000000100005fdc __38-[DVTDispatchLock
>   performLockedBlock:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTFoundation)   4 
>   0x00007fff87886fbb dispatch_barrier_sync_f (in libSystem.B.dylib)   5 
>   0x0000000100005f83 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in
>   DVTFoundation)   6  0x000000010055ccd3 -[IDESourceControlWorkingTree
>   mergeStatusOperationResults:forLocalStatusOnly:] (in IDEFoundation)
>   7  0x00000001005db64c __77-[IDESourceControlWorkingTree
>   updateLocalStatusForDirectory:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_01137 (in
>   IDEFoundation)   8  0x00007fff8788dd64
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libSystem.B.dylib)   9 
>   0x00007fff8786c8d2 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libSystem.B.dylib)  10 
>   0x00007fff8786c734 _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libSystem.B.dylib)  11 
>   0x00007fff8786c2de _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libSystem.B.dylib)  12
>   0x00007fff8786bc08 _pthread_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)  13 
>   0x00007fff8786baa5 start_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have duplicate entries for the source code repository for this project.  Go under Organizer and remove the duplicate and see if fixes the issue.  Unfortunately, there are still a lot of bugs in the SCM tooling in XCode 4.

Comment: +1, Yes, I had multiple entries and I have now removed all but one, but Xcode does still crash. Maybe I can remove everything from my computer and then download it from subversion again?

Comment: There is a way that you could solve this - I think.  It involves removing the SVN cache that XCode has built up - but I can't seem to find the article that I used when I ran into this.  Re-installing XCode might/might not actually solve the issue.